# Questions on Projection Equality and Orthogonal Vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have these two questions from my Calculus III homework:

**Find all unit vectors that are orthogonal to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, and justify your answer**

**When does projection of $u$ on $v$ = projection of $v$ on $u$? Justify your answer**

For the first question, I've tried to use the basic definition of an two orthogonal vectors, $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} = 0$, however I'm stuck with $x\cos(θ)+y\sin(θ)=0$. Of course I can consider the zero vector, but I'm not sure that's the only answer. I've heard of using the rotation matrix, though I don't to use it nor how it works. I don't know what do from here.

For the second question, I don't know what to do at all.

Any advice helps.

Comment: I also don't know how to format math letters or equations online, so I know this may not look good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

**Question 1:** If a vector is on the unit circle, it must be of the form $(x,y)=(\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$. This gives, when plugged into your equation, $$\cos \phi \cos \theta+\sin \phi \sin \theta=0.$$
All that remains is to apply the formula $\cos(\phi-\theta)=\cos \phi \cos \theta+\sin \phi \sin \theta$. I'll leave that for you.

**Question 2:** Are we talking about the length of the projection, or the projection itself? I assume we're talking about the length of the projection (i.e., the dot product). If $\mathbf{u}=(u_1,u_2)$ and $\mathbf{v}=(v_1,v_2)$, use the formula for the dot product is:
$$\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}= u_1v_1+u_2v_2,$$
and the answer to your question follows directly from this. You can also draw out the projection of the vector $\mathbf{u}$ onto $\mathbf{v}$ and the projection of $\mathbf{v}$ onto $\mathbf{u}$ in the same diagram, and use high school geometry to prove that they are of equal length.

Comment: How did you make the connection of using the unit circle in the first question?

Comment: The unit vectors are the collection of points on the unit circle.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to answer the first question after using the trigonometric identity. Would I just solve for Phi and Theta and then use those values to find the unit vectors?

Comment: I also don't quite get your explanations for the second question. I'm not quite sure if the question is refering to the length or the projection itself, what is the difference? The only conclusion I can make is when both u and v are the same. As for the geometric approach, it seems as though the projections are not the same. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: For the first question, you get that $\cos(\phi-\theta)=0$, so you must have $\phi = \theta \pm \pi/2$. Plug this back into the expression for the unit vector $(\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi))$ to get your answer.

Comment: For the second question, refer to the definition of projection. The projection of one vector onto another is a vector, while the length of the projection is a scalar.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. We're talking about the projection itself then, not the length.

Comment: Then this would only be the case if $u=v$.

Comment: Yeah it seemed like that would be the only case. What if we were talking about the length? Could you further explain your method?

Comment: If we were talking about the length, then: $u \cdot v = u_1v_1 + u_2v_2 = v_1u_1+v_2u_2 = v \cdot u$, so the answer is that they are always equal.